# Generate files with passing arguments using python

Tags: python

I would like to generate files using python is such way.
For example, I have `script_1.aas` file. Inside it, there are 2 parameters which are actually a different path of a network, in the example below, there are 2 folders `script_1` in different path :

`...;
char const * const outputDir = "output\\script_1";
...
success = readNetworkWithLogLevel( net, "network\\script_1", LOGLEVEL_WARNING);`

I would like to generate or create files using python with the same content and changing only these two parameters with the corresponding number (from 1 to 20), for example, 20 of `script_1` with incrementing the number one by one. `script_1, script_2, ... script_20`.

Comment: And your question is... what? You are not familiar with python at all, so you'd like someone to do this for you? And you are not familiar with any other programming language either, so that is also not an option for you?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar, but I dont know how to do it

Comment: The general idea is: do what you can. At that point you will have some more specific questions, which you can look up in python specification, google, existing answers on SO. After that, you may still have some even more specific questions for which you do not have an answer and which are suitable for a question on SO. The way it is now, the question is too broad. What I could give you as an answer now is use [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to open a file and [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to write to it.

Comment: Do you know how to [read from and write to files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)?  ... Which version of python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file:

```
with open('script_1.aas') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Iterate through the numbers 2-20; use string formatting to construct new strings and replace `script_1` with `script_n`; write to a new file.

```
for n in range(2,20):
    new_content = content.replace('script_1', f'script_{n}')
    with open(f'script_{n}.aas', 'w') as f:
        f.write(new_content)
```

For python versions 2.7-3.5 replace

- `f'script_{n}'` with `'script_{}'.format(n)`
- `f'script_{n}.aas'` with `'script_{}.aas'.format(n)`

---

[f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
[String formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)